# Автозапуск скрипта

Tags: linux, bash, debian, autoload, daemon

Написал скрипт, который после запуска ОС в зависимости от некоторых данных запускает или убивает графическую программу. Графический сервер тоже запускается из данного скрипта, но после запуска сервера, заданная программа не запускается на графике, но все вводы и выводы из порта /dev/ttyS3 выполняются. Вот скрипт:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    startx &
    sleep 4

    stty -F /dev/ttyS3 raw ispeed 9600 ospeed 9600 -ignpar cs8 -cstopb -echo
    pid=0
    control=0
    info=0
    pid=`ps -e | grep squeakvm | awk '{print $1}'`
    if (( ${#pid} > 3 ))
    then
            kill $pid
    fi
    echo "35" > /dev/ttyS3


    while true
    do
            pid=`ps -e | grep squeakvm | awk '{print $1}'`
            info=`head -c1 /dev/ttyS3`

            if [ "$info" == "a" ];then
                    #echo "a" > /dev/ttyS3
                    if (( ${#pid} > 3 ));then
                            kill $pid
                            echo $pid
                            echo "28" > /dev/ttyS3
                            sleep 1
                            echo "35" > /dev/ttyS3
                    else
                            echo "46" > /dev/ttyS3
                            sleep 1
                            echo "17" > /dev/ttyS3
                            squeakvm /root/squeakvm/default.sb &
                    fi
            fi

            if [ "$info" == "b" ];then
                    #echo "b" > /dev/ttyS3
                    echo "37" > /dev/ttyS3
                    poweroff
                    exit 0
            fi
    done
    exit 0
```

Но если отдельно запустить Графический сервер, а потом там в терминале запустить данный скрипт, то все работает, но мне нужно, чтобы автоматически при старте все заработало.
Скрипт запускается из /etc/rc.local

ОС - Linux Debian

Версиия ядра - 3.2

Графическая среда - X Window System

Comment: конкретизируйте вопрос, пожалуйста. естественно, не в форме «как сделать, чтобы всё работало». с такой формулировкой следует обращаться на какую-нибудь биржу фрилансеров.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin если запустить данный скрипт в консоли, то после команды startx запускается графический сервер и нормально работает с файлами (echo "35" > /dev/ttyS3 - эта команда мигает светодиодом) , но запуск программы "squeakvm" не происходит. Но при случае запуска скрипта из эмулятора терминала, после ручного запуска Xorg, все работает нормально. Как сразу автоматически запускать вторым способом?

Comment: из `man startx`: `startx x-клиент опции-для-x-клиента`. например: `startx xterm опции-для-xterm`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а можно подробнее? Я могу запустить скрипт таким образом в эмуляторе терминала?

Comment: подробнее — в документации (упомянута выше). да, можете. но раз вы упомянули про «x-эмулятор терминала», то, значит, как минимум один x-сервер у вас запущен. и по умолчанию номер дисплея `0` уже занят, поэтому надо передать новому экземпляру другой номер, например, `1`: `startx x-клиент опции-для-x-клиента -- :1`